# How to setting "community site" navigation in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

In Team site i can see in site settings:

[image]

But in Community site , I just can see

[image]

How can I make community site show all items of “Look and Feel” like Team site

Answer (score 0):

This need to activate Publishing feature.

1. Go to Site Collection Features, activate this:

[image]

2. Go to Site Features,activate this:

[image]

Then it will show up:

[image]